# Whether there is a better way to update tappable area after change viewport/camera zoom?

Tags: flutter, flame

I have a tappable object inside my game. I set position and size, therefore onTap functions work fine. But when I change camera viewport or zoom, then tappable area doesnt work correctly (it takes old position and size of object, before camera change).

I know that tapping base on containsLocalPoint function, but does exist any simple way to resolve that instead of calculating everything on my own?

Comment: That should already be solved by Flame, are you using the Camera that is built-in on the FlameGame class or the CameraComponent?

Comment: built-in Camera

Comment: This definitely already works in Flame, how do you define your component? Can you post the full code for the component in the question? :)